# php-mysql for MySQL-server (case sensitive)

Tags: mysql

I don't know how but it seems there are two different versions of mysql probably from different yum repositories :

```
yum list | grep  mysql
MySQL-server.x86_64                        5.5.9-1.linux2.6            installed
mysql-server.x86_64                        5.1.47-1.2.amzn1            amzn
```

I need to install php-mysql which is available only for the version that is not installed (5.1.47-1.2.amzn1), if I run yum install php-mysql there is a conflict with the other MySQL-server (5.5.9-1.linux2.6)..

```
yum install php-mysql
.
.
.
Transaction Check Error:
  file /usr/share/mysql/charsets/cp1251.xml from install of mysql-libs-5.1.47-1.2.amzn1.x86_64 conflicts with file from package MySQL-server-5.5.9-1.linux2.6.x86_64
```

As the current MySQL-server with uppercase letters is currently installed and used in production I can't uninstall it and install the other version wehre the php-mysql package is compatible.

How can I install php-mysql for the MySQL-server (5.5.9-1.linux2.6) ? why there are two versions of mysql-servers ?

Any help will be appreciated..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just had a similar problem when trying to install geoip-devel (GeoIP-devel version 1.4.5 in repo extras, geoip-devel version 1.4.6 in repo rpmforge). Mine was solved by excluding the rpmforge:

```
yum install --disablerepo=rpmforge GeoIP-devel
```

I guess your problem is with several repos supplying different versions, maybe you can use yum downgrade (possibly with the --disablerepo option)?